# textMessage.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm creating some text animation using css and javascript. I have two sections that share the same classes. I'm selecting the classes in javascript using querySelectorAll and then using forEach to apply my if statement to each section of the two sections that share the same classes. However I'm getting the console error textMessage.getBoundingClientRect is not a function.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone shed any light?

```js
function scrollAppear() {
  const textMessage = document.querySelectorAll('.home-message-text');
  let textPosition = textMessage.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let screenPosition = window.innerHeight;
  textMessage.forEach(function(textMessage) {
    if (textPosition < screenPosition) {
      textMessage.classList.add('.home-message-text-appear');
    }
  });

}
```

```css
.homepage-message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 7rem;
  padding-right: 6rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

.homepage-message-text {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 70rem;
  padding-top: 10rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: 1.5s all ease-in-out;
}

.home-message-text-appear {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <section class="homepage-message container">
    <div class="homepage-message-text">
      <h2 class="title">Some Type Of Title One</h2>
      <p class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A eligendi ipsum, veniam aliquid assumenda incidunt? Rem perspiciatis eveniet exercitationem velit repellat eaque est ad, vitae animi saepe, dolorem quos officia. Corrupti, accusamus! Maxime
        exercitationem accusamus quibusdam similique minus, recusandae veniam veritatis sequi aliquid labore, ad sit minima! Porro ut officia repudiandae facilis, similique officiis sapiente. Dolorum vitae sint quaerat facere.
      </p>

    </div>


  </section>

  <section class="homepage-message container">
    <div class="homepage-message-text">
      <h2 class="title">Some Type Of Title Two</h2>
      <p class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A eligendi ipsum, veniam aliquid assumenda incidunt? Rem perspiciatis eveniet exercitationem velit repellat eaque est ad, vitae animi saepe, dolorem quos officia. Corrupti, accusamus! Maxime
        exercitationem accusamus quibusdam similique minus, recusandae veniam veritatis sequi aliquid labore, ad sit minima! Porro ut officia repudiandae facilis, similique officiis sapiente. Dolorum vitae sint quaerat facere.
      </p>

    </div>


  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*querySelectorAll* returns *NodeList* which doesn't have *getBoundingClientRect* method.
You should move it inside forEach and call it on each node.

Answer (score 0):

There's several things going on in here, starting with what Andy stated as you need to deal with an array of nodes instead of direct elements.

Next issue would be in your var hoisting where `textPosition` needs to come from each individual element itself.

After that, when you add a css class you would simply `add` the name without the period so the reference is complete.

See edited below and have a great weekend!

```js
function scrollAppear() {
  const textMessage = document.querySelectorAll('.homepage-message');
  let screenPosition = window.innerHeight;
  
  if (textMessage.length > 0) {
   
    for (i = 0, x = textMessage.length; i < x; i++) {
    
      let textPosition = textMessage[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
            
      if (textPosition < screenPosition) {
        textMessage[i].classList.add('home-message-text-appear');
        console.log('HEY WE ADDED THE CLASS TO THIS ELEMENT THAT MET CRITERIA - ', textMessage[i]);
      }
    }
    
  } else {
    console.warn('No elements with the class found');
  }

}

scrollAppear();
```

```css
.homepage-message-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 7rem;
  padding-right: 6rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

.homepage-message-text {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 70rem;
  padding-top: 10rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
}

.home-message-text-appear {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  border: green 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <section class="homepage-message container">
    <div class="homepage-message-text">
      <h2 class="title">Some Type Of Title One</h2>
      <p class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A eligendi ipsum, veniam aliquid assumenda incidunt? Rem perspiciatis eveniet exercitationem velit repellat eaque est ad, vitae animi saepe, dolorem quos officia. Corrupti, accusamus! Maxime
        exercitationem accusamus quibusdam similique minus, recusandae veniam veritatis sequi aliquid labore, ad sit minima! Porro ut officia repudiandae facilis, similique officiis sapiente. Dolorum vitae sint quaerat facere.
      </p>

    </div>


  </section>

  <section class="homepage-message container">
    <div class="homepage-message-text">
      <h2 class="title">Some Type Of Title Two</h2>
      <p class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A eligendi ipsum, veniam aliquid assumenda incidunt? Rem perspiciatis eveniet exercitationem velit repellat eaque est ad, vitae animi saepe, dolorem quos officia. Corrupti, accusamus! Maxime
        exercitationem accusamus quibusdam similique minus, recusandae veniam veritatis sequi aliquid labore, ad sit minima! Porro ut officia repudiandae facilis, similique officiis sapiente. Dolorum vitae sint quaerat facere.
      </p>

    </div>


  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

textPosition was outside the scope of my forEach loop.

```js
function scrollAppear() {
  const textMessage = document.querySelectorAll('.homepage-message-text');
  let screenPosition = window.innerHeight;
  textMessage.forEach(function(section) {
    let textPosition = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (textPosition < screenPosition) {
      section.classList.add('home-message-text-appear');
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollAppear);
```